# Reduce the default width of mat-tab

Tags: angular, mat-tab

[image]I would like to use mat-tab-group in a mobile app. The problem is the default width is bigger than my windows app. i would like to know how can i reduce the default width of mat-tab-group.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to reduce the width of the mat-tab-group.

1) Provide a custom class to your  directive. 
On your component.html, we have added the `.custom-tab-group` class to the mat tab directive.

```
<mat-tab-group class="custom-tab-group">
    .
    .
    .
</mat-tab-group>
```

And on your css, define the class with the following properties

```
.custom-tab-group {
  width:200px
}
```

Check out the working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bmdpy9?file=app/tab-group-basic-example.css).

2) Overwrite the `.mat-tab-group` class on your main style.css. It is the one that is on the same directory level as your index.html, main.ts, package.json, etc. You might need to add the !important declaration. Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pcckwn?file=styles.css).

```
.mat-tab-group {
  width: 200px!important;
}
```

3) On the component that uses the mat-tab, you will need to use the `/deep/` shadow piercing to force the style. However, I would not recommend this method, as it will soon be [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep). If you wish to use it, you will need to add the following css properties on your component.css file,

```
/deep/.mat-tab-group {
 width: 200px!important; /* you might or might not need to use the !important declaration */
}
```

I have added a working demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tar5g7?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.css).

Comment: I already did it. But it add a scroll. I would like to place my three tab in the screen without scroll

Comment: I would like to adapt the tabs according to my screen without scroll bar

Comment: What scroll are you referring to? The horizontal scroll on your window?? Or vertical?

Comment: The horizontal scroll

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dynamicHeight` property for mat-tab-group which will allow the tab group to grow to the size of active tab.

```
  <mat-tab-group
    dynamicHeight
       ...
       ...
       ...
  >
    <mat-tab label="Tab 1">
       ...
       ...
       ...
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 2">
       ...
       ...
       ...
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
```